# How many versions of Kat were there in the car chase sequence in Tenet?

Tags: plot-explanation, tenet

From other posts, it seems like she was never inverted during the car chase and warehouse sequence, therefore there should be only 1 version of her floating around (until she is taken into the turnstile by protagonist). Time is always going forward for her.

So how then is she driven to the warehouse initially by Sator and also dragged backwards to the warehouse by Sator (who is inversed) in the same time period? When Sator inverses and pushes her into the car (is time now running backwards for Kat?). If it isn't, then surely there are two versions of her floating around. I am confused.

Comment: I've added a reply to the above linked post and it should clear it up.